# Declaring objects of type option in Java

Tags: java, swing

How is it possible to declare an object of type `option` in Java? I was told that the following code would convert a Vector of Strings into a Vector of Option, but `new Option(String)` is not a valid constructor:

```
private <T> Vector<Option> convertToOptions( Vector<T> convert )
{
     Vector<Option> options = new Vector<Option>();
     for ( T temp : convert )
          options.add( new Option( temp.toString() ) );
     return options;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the constructor for the Option class?

Comment: And Option is what exactly, your own class? Part of a framework?

Comment: Is this meant to be like a Scala `Option`?  Check what class you're really importing... Make sure your not accidentally importing `javax.swing.text.html.Option`.

Comment: It is option type for Javax.swing.text.html.Option. This project involves creating a Java Web App and drop down boxes take arrays, Collections, or Maps of type Option.

Comment: @Greg Kopff... wow. For some reason what you said totally went over my head. After I had some monstrosity block of code that involved 6 casts and it still didn't work, I noticed that the package I need is `com.sun.webui.jsf.model.Option`. There's 90 minutes down the drain. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might need to create an `AttributeSet` and then convert it to an `Option`? Something like this...

```
SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
for ( T temp : convert ){
    set.add(temp.getName(),temp.getValue());
    }
Option option = new Option(set);
```

Otherwise, if you're creating a dropdown, are you using `JComboBox`? If so, this has a `JComboBox(Vector)` constructor - might be much easier. Otherwise, what class are you using to create the dropdown?